# Send dictionary in python socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sockets

I want to send dictionary via python socket.

I tried to encode sending data and then encode at the receiving point

but the problem in unconvertable received data and can not convert to dictionary.

Here is my code:

Class `client.py`:

```
HEADER_LENGTH = 512
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 963

my_username = input("Username: ")
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
client_socket.setblocking(False)
username = my_username.encode('utf-8')
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
client_socket.send(username_header + username)
while True:
    message = input(f"{my_username} > ")
    if message:
        message = message.encode('utf-8')
        message_header = f"{len(message)}:<{HEADER_LENGTH}".encode('utf-8')
        # {'header': {message_header}, 'data': {message}}
        send_dict = {} # 'header': message_header, 'data': message
        send_dict["header"] = str(message_header)
        send_dict["data"] = str(message)
        client_socket.send(json.dumps(send_dict).encode('utf-8'))  # message_header + message
    try:
        while True:
            # Receive ...
            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            if not len(username_header):
                print("Connection closed by the server")
                sys.exit()
            username_length = int(username_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode(('utf-8'))

            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
            message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode(('utf-8'))
            print(f"{username} > {message}")

    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            print('Reading error', str(e))
            sys.exit()
        continue
    except Exception as e:
        print('General error', str(e))
        sys.exit()
```

Class `server.py`:

```
HEADER_LENGTH = 512
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 963

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen()

socket_list = [server_socket]
clients = {}


def receive_message(client_socket):
    # print(f"client socket: {client_socket}")
    # try:
    message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
    if not len(message_header):
        print("return from receive message /condition/")
        return False
    print(f"message header: {type(message_header)}")
    print(f"message header: {message_header}")
    print(f"message header decode : {type(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())}")
    message_header_dict = message_header.decode('utf-8').strip()
    # print(f"message header replaced : {message_header}")
    print(f"message header replaced : {type(message_header_dict)}")
    print(f"message header replaced : {message_header_dict}")
    # print("message header header : " + message_header_dict['header'].decode('utf-8').strip())
    json_message_header = json.loads(message_header_dict)
    print(f"message header replaced : {json_message_header}")
    print(f"message header replaced : {json_message_header['data']}") # Error line
    message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
    return {"header": message_header, "data": client_socket.recv(message_length)}
    # except:
        # print("return from receive message /except/")
        # return False


while True:
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(socket_list, [], socket_list)
    for notified_socket in read_sockets:
        if notified_socket == server_socket:
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            user = receive_message(client_socket)
            if user == False:
                continue
            socket_list.append(client_socket)
            clients[client_socket] = user
            print(
                f"Accept new connection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} username:{user['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
        else:
            message = receive_message(notified_socket)
            if message == False:
                print(f"close connection from: {clients[notified_socket]['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
                socket_list.remove(notified_socket)
                del clients[notified_socket]
                continue
            user = clients[notified_socket]
            print(f"Received message from: {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}: {message['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
            for client_socket in clients:
                if client_socket != notified_socket:
                    client_socket.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])
    for notified_socket in exception_sockets:
        socket_list.remove(notified_socket)
        del clients[notified_socket]
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Show us the errors.

Answer (score 5):

Your client sends JSON. Your server then reads the entire JSON message and tries to interpret it as an integer. Boom.

You basically have 3 options for transferring the full message: Send bytes and assume you receive the entire message and no more from a single read (least reliable); use a delimiter (*e.g.*, CRLF) and make sure it doesn't appear in the message (restricted data stream); or send a byte-count followed by the message bytes (length+data, the most reliable). It looks like you've mixed the first and third approaches, which basically never works.

To serialize a dict for transmission as JSON using length+data, first JSON-encode the dict, then UTF8-encode the resultant string to get the message bytes. From this point until the server deserializes the message, the code is working with bytes.

To send length+data, the `struct` module is your friend. Define the pack/unpack specifier (basically, selected-size integer plus bytestring). For example, `"!Hs"` would support message bytestrings up to 64K.

In the client...

- Get the encoded length of the UTF8-encoded message string.
- Use `struct.pack` to create the binary message (<length-header><message-bytes>).
- Use `socket.sendall` to send the binary message (sending the message may take multiple `send` calls, and `sendall` takes care of that for you).

In the server...

- Use `socket.recv` to receive *just the header bytes* (*e.g.*, 4 or 8 bytes).
- Unpack the byte count using `struct.unpack`.
- Use `socket.recv` to receive *just the message bytes* (*i.e.*, *byte_count* bytes)
- To deserialize the dict from the received (serialized) message bytes, UTF8-decode then JSON-decode.

Answer (score 0):

you could use pickle or its faster version cPickle to serialize data and deserialize data.

```
import pickle

# for serializing data 
pickle.dumps(data_to_serialized)
# for deserializing 
pickle.loads(data_to_be_deserialized)
```

Here is sample function for sending and receiving data using pickle for serialization:

```
def send_data(conn, data):
        serialized_data = pickle.dumps(data)
        conn.sendall(struct.pack('>I', len(serialized_data)))
        conn.sendall(serialized_data)


def receive_data(conn):
    data_size = struct.unpack('>I', conn.recv(4))[0]
    received_payload = b""
    reamining_payload_size = data_size
    while reamining_payload_size != 0:
        received_payload += conn.recv(reamining_payload_size)
        reamining_payload_size = data_size - len(received_payload)
    data = pickle.loads(received_payload)

    return data
```

you could find sample program at https://github.com/vijendra1125/Python-Socket-Programming.git